# Party Data Modeling

Tags: database-design, data-modeling, datamodel, ofbiz

Reference question/Answer posted on the party data modeling

[How to model party relationship data in ofbiz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820972/how-to-model-party-relationship-data-in-ofbiz/53102788#53102788)

Need to get clarity on the below, Pls. assist

Can anyone explain why will we have duplicate data in the Party Relationship entity(I tried to depict thru an e.g. attached (party role example where we cant have duplicates). Why do we need to have From Date as part of the key?? Pls. explain.[party role example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTJTk.png)

Comment: Hi. This is not clear. Please use enough words & sentences & references to parts of examples to be clear. PS Please include whatever you need to answer this question in this question, but only what you need to, and explain how it relates to your question. But please use text, not images/links, for text. That includes tables & using (pseudo-)DDL for ERDs. If you want to augment text or give what can't be given in text then also add an image. Always include any legend needed for understanding an image/link.

Answer (score 3):

Apache OFBiz follows **The Universal Data Model** by **Len Silverston**, with a grain of salt. Please refer to the [book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=XkBPl4Ted40C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false) for better understanding.

A Party can be in more than one roles in a system. PartyRole entity stores what roles a Party has in the system but with whom is stored in PartyRelationship entity.

For example:
Let's say there are 2 companies in OFBiz, Company A and Company B. If John is an employee of Company A. John will have an entry in PartyRole with role Employee and an entry in PartyRelationship for its relationship with Company A.

Please refer following mail [thread](https://ofbiz.markmail.org/thread/4od2ulk6ufoivhu7) too.

> Now, these relationships are not indefinite. An employee is in a role for
>   a certain time period only. So, the fromDate and thruDate represents
>   that particular time period.

You can also use Apache OFBiz user mailing [list](https://ofbiz.apache.org/mailing-lists.html) for such queries.

HTH